# Is there a way to make `genstrings` work with `LocalizedStringKey`?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, genstrings

Is there a  way get Apple's `genstrings` command line tool to recognize localizable string keys defined from `SwiftUI`'s `LocalizedStringKey` initializer?

For this input file (`testing-genstrings.swift`): ...

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

enum L10n {
    static let test0 = NSLocalizedString("TEST0", comment: "")

    static let test1 = LocalizedStringKey("TEST1")

    static func test2(_ parameter: String) -> LocalizedStringKey {
        return LocalizedStringKey("TEST2_\(parameter)")
    }

    static func test3(_ parameter: String) -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString("TEST3_\(parameter)", comment: "")
    }

    static func test4(_ parameter: String) -> String {
        return String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("TEST4", comment: ""), parameter)
    }
}

let test5 = "TEST5"
let test6 = "TEST6"
let test7 = "TEST7"

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(L10n.test0)
            Text(L10n.test1)
            Text(L10n.test2("foo"))
            Text(L10n.test3("bar"))
            Text(test5)
            Text(LocalizedStringKey(test6))
            Text(NSLocalizedString(test7, ""))
            Text("TEST8")
            Text("TEST9_\("baz")")
        }
    }
}
```

...`genstrings` generates this output:

```sh
$ genstrings -SwiftUI -s LocalizedStringKey testing-genstrings.swift && iconv -c -f utf-16 -t utf-8 Localizable.strings
genstrings: error: bad entry in file testing-genstrings.swift (line = 9): Argument is not a literal string.
genstrings: error: bad entry in file testing-genstrings.swift (line = 11): Argument is not a literal string.
genstrings: error: bad entry in file testing-genstrings.swift (line = 12): Argument is not a literal string.
genstrings: error: bad entry in file testing-genstrings.swift (line = 36): Argument is not a literal string.
genstrings: error: bad entry in file testing-genstrings.swift (line = 37): Argument is not a literal string.
genstrings: error: bad entry in file testing-genstrings.swift (line = 37): Argument is not a literal string.
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"bar" = "bar";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"foo" = "foo";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"TEST0" = "TEST0";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"TEST3_\(parameter)" = "TEST3_\(parameter)";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"TEST4" = "TEST4";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"TEST8" = "TEST8";

/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"TEST9_%@" = "TEST9_%@";
```

You can see that it recognizes the keys defined via `NSLocalizedString` and `Text`'s initializer Text() initializer that uses `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` (`TEST9_%@` in the example), but fails on all keys defined using `LocalizedStringKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`genstrings` is relatively naive. It is looking for a function with two parameters, the first unnamed, the second named "comment".

If you added the following extension:

```swift
public extension LocalizedStringKey {
    init(_ value: String, comment: String) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

and always used that, you'd be able to use `LocalizedStringKey` by passing `-s LocalizedStringKey` to `genstrings`.

Keep in mind that if you declared `LocalizedStringKey` as a return type or a variable, that would give a `genstrings` error, too. So you'd need a separate `typealias LocalizedStringKeyResult = LocalizedStringKey` that you use when reference `LocalizedStringKey` but don't want `genstrings` to complain.

And, of course, you wouldn't get the interpolation you want because `genstrings` applies that only to `Text`.

The real answer is... don't use `LocalizedStringKey`. Use `Text` when you can (to get interpolation). Use `NSLocalizedString` when you can't.